# Stop service in an activity

Tags: android, service, android-intentservice

I'm using following code to stop my service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UsageRecorderService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

And this is my service that works indefinitely

```
public class UsageRecorderService extends IntentService {

  public UsageRecorderService() {
      super("UsageRecorder");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

      while (true) {

          UsageRecorder.recordUsages(this, false);

          SystemClock.sleep(10000);
      }
   }
}
```

Why does not stop my service?

Comment: The answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709989/how-to-stop-intentservice-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code would work

```
public class UsageRecorderService extends IntentService {

    private boolean mStop = false;

    public UsageRecorderService() {
        super("UsageRecorder");
    }

    public final Object sLock = new Object();

    public void onDestroy() {
        synchronized (sLock) {
            mStop = true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (sLock) {
                if (mStop) break;
            }
            UsageRecorder.recordUsages(this, false);
            SystemClock.sleep(10000);
        }
    }

}
```

You can use `stopService`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UsageRecorderService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

Also I recommend to read [Services guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to understand what is going there.

Comment: May you explain the synchronized and sLock

Comment: @MousaJafari both are for [Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) of read/write `mStop` field at different threads

Comment: @gio Is it possible to use mStop as lock instead?

Answer (score 0):

Activity:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_STOP));
```

IntentService

```
public class UsageRecorderService extends IntentService {
  private static final String TAG  = "UsageRecorderService";
  String ACTION_STOP = "com.xxx.UsageRecorderService.ACTION_STOP";
  boolean stop;

  public UsageRecorderService() {
    super("UsageRecorder");
  }

  private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (ACTION_STOP.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        stop = true;
      }
    }
  };

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_STOP);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG,"onHandleIntent");
    while (true && !stop) {
      Log.i(TAG,"----running----");
      //UsageRecorder.recordUsages(this, false);
      SystemClock.sleep(10000);
    }
  }

  @Override public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250745/proper-way-to-stop-intentservice/10250896#10250896

Comment: I've tested it and does not work, Maybe the problem is my while loop?

Comment: `stopService(intent);` won't call `onHandleIntent`

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake.use `startService(intent)`

Comment: `onHandleIntent` won't be called after 1st `startService`

Comment: Yep, I just realize that your `handleIntent()` is always running because the `while(ture)`, so my answer won't not work. `BroadcastReceiver` is another choice

Answer (score 0):

An IntentService is designed to stop itself only when all the requests present in the work queue have been handled.Android stops the service after all start requests have been handled.