# Android service does not stop when calling stopService()

Tags: java, android, service

so im developing a service for a application locker. the main activity has a switch which just toggles between starting and stopping a service using `startService()` and `stopService()` respectively. The problem is when i try to stop the service it does not stop immediately. i have no idea how to stop it. I've even tried adding `stopself()` in the `onDestroy()` of my service but it doesn't work

My Code

```
public class LockerService extends Service {

String LockedApps[];
String allowedapp = null;
DataBaseHandler handler;
private ExecutorService executorService;
private ActivityManager activityManager = null;
String[] AppActivities = { .... };

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if (executorService != null) {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
    stopSelf();
    executorService.shutdown();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service stopped",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    LockerThread thread = new LockerThread();
    executorService.submit(thread);
    handler = new DataBaseHandler(this);
}

class LockerThread implements Runnable {

    Intent pwdIntent = null;

    public LockerThread() {
        pwdIntent = new Intent(LockerService.this, Locker.class);
        pwdIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            handler.open();
            LockedApps = handler.getPackages();
            boolean status = handler.checkdata("PACKAGE");
            handler.close();
            while (status) {
                String packname = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                        .getPackageName();
                String activityname = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1)
                        .get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(LockerService.this);
                allowedapp = sp.getString("allowedapp", "anon");
                // Log.i("activity name", activityname);
                if ((packname.equals("com.packagename"))
                        && (allowedapp.equals("com.packagename"))) {
                    // do nothing
                } else if ((packname.equals("com.packagename"))
                        && !(Arrays.asList(AppActivities)
                                .contains(activityname))) {

                    try {
                        Editor edit = sp.edit();
                        edit.putString("current_app", packname);
                        edit.commit();
                        startActivity(pwdIntent);
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if ((Arrays.asList(LockedApps).contains(packname))
                        && (allowedapp.equals(packname))) {
                    // do nothing
                } else if ((Arrays.asList(LockedApps).contains(packname))) {
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("current_app", packname);
                    edit.commit();
                    startActivity(pwdIntent);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have a look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/service-wont-stop-when-stopservice-method-is-called

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459885/stop-service-in-an-activity

Comment: FYI, what you're trying to do is futile.  In Android 4, if you run this as a foreground service, the user can access the status bar (even in a full screen activity) and easily kill the service.  If you don't run it as a foreground service, then it might be killed without warning if the app that started it leaves the foreground even for an instant, completely defeating the purpose.  And the hack you're using to determine the foreground activity (`activityManager.getRunningTasks(1)`) is deliberately broken in Android 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're stopping the service but the thread is still executing..you need to stop the thread .. since you have a `while(true)` loop is suggest you assign a boolean variable which will be set to true on start and false on destroy and chenge the while to while(boolean_variable)

Comment: That boolean needs to be `volatile`.